# send formdata using javascript and receive in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, content-disposition

How to access element from content-Disposition from PHP ? Here, formdata is sending through javascript. If Content type isn't set as form-urlencoded, it will return empty string.

```
var fdata = new FormData();
fdata.append('id',id);
fdata.append('img',nwImg);
fdata.append('hdng',hdng);
fdata.append('cntnt',cntnt);

var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(xhr){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
    {
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlHttp.open("post", "http://localhost/dashcntrl/file/upld"); 
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.send(fdata);
```

But content-Disposition is attached while assign setRequestHeader in JavaScript. It will return while returning `print_r($_POST)`

```
Array
(
[-----------------------------18619978915867
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "id"

-----------------------------18619978915867
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="img"


-----------------------------18619978915867
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hdng"

5
-----------------------------18619978915867
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cntnt"

)
```

How to access name and value without Content-Disposition

Comment: Remove `xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: By the way you can also use `xhr.onload = function(){}` so you don't have to test for `xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4`. Just a comment.

Comment: does image will send without `xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`

Comment: Are you getting that image on an `<input id='whatever' type='file' accept='image/*' />`, like `const fd = new FormData; document.getElementById('whatever').onchange = function(event){ const files = event.files; if(files.length){ const file = files[0]; fd.append('imageFilesSuperglobalName', file); } }`? Keep in mind asynchronous behavior, as  well.